Create color-font from ai- or svg-files

I have a colored vector-graphik Jh.ai (original) and Jh.svg (export) as an example of a playing card (I used 'AdobeIllustrator' for the 'export'; because I didn't know how to do it any other way). 
Another example is 2s.ai and 2s.svg (I can also add any other cards from the 52 deck). 

Upload of these example-files at _GitHub

I want to create a ttf-color-font-file which is of the type and can be used like TwemojiMozilla.ttf (CTAN) (which is in TeXLive included); excerpt: 
 
(I think  TwemojiMozilla.ttf  is the COLR/CPAL palette.)
In the result, I would like to use this in a LaTeX-document as shown below (but I think the correct result could be used with "Word" etc. in an appropriate way).
Could somebody explain what I have to do?
I have 'Fontforge' and 'Fontlab 8' (I don't know whether this these are the right softwares): FontForge does not like color-fonts much. Fontlab 8 wants to make me an output test-svg.ttf and test.ttf; and I get black pictures in the LaTeX-output below.
% arara: lualatex
\documentclass{article}  

\usepackage{fontspec}  
\newfontfamily\myfontA[Renderer=HarfBuzz]{TwemojiMozilla.ttf}

\begin{document}
\section{TwemojiMozilla.ttf -- vectors}
{\Huge\myfontA  
\char"1F0CF % Joker
\char"1F600 % Smiley
}
\end{document}

Hint: I added the "adobe illustrator tag", because the original-files are from the *.ai-format.

Very good question.

The simplest solution I know of, given that you already have Illustrator, is the Fontself plugin. It has all of the functionality you would need for this purpose, and is much easier to get along with than Fontlab. (I have nothing against Fontlab, but I don't believe in using an industrial laser when an X-Acto will do just as good a job.)

If you have Fontself, could you test whether it works for 1 glyph?

I don't know everything about the program, but I tested "Fontself Maker" and noticed that it doesn't adopt the colors of the source ai file.

There is a help page at help.fontself.com, with "Making fonts" tutorials covering this, and even a video by Monika Gause on how to make color fonts with Fontself.
